# Difference between phrases in Complex Object

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the following sentences?

1. I want the watch repaired.
2. I want the watch to be repaired.
3. I want to have the watch repaired.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks for your question. Do you have a specific question about these sentences? "How are they different" doesn't give us much to go on! Please use the [edit] link to tell us what _you_ think are the differences. We need to know what research you have done. Also, please take a few minutes to review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. We hope you will ask more questions!

Answer (score 1):

> I want the watch repaired.

You want an action to be taken that results in the a repaired watch.

> I want the watch to be repaired.

You want plans to be made to repair the watch.

> I want to have the watch repaired.

You want someone else other than yourself or the listener to repair the watch.

Comment: I disagree slightly. The first and the second are identical. Otherwise, you have it right.